# How to call a stored procedure in neo4jclient?

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I'd like to call a stored procedure (see a previous question:[Question with stored procedure for Neo4J as the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37878115/370174) However, I can't quite see a way of doing that through the fluent query interface.

Can anyone help?

My Cypher query:

```
MATCH(user:UserAccount)-[:HasPermission]->(permission:Permission)
WITH user, collect(permission) as permissions
CALL apoc.map.setKey( user, 'permissions', permissions ) YIELD value as UserAccount
RETURN UserAccount
```

My Neo4jClient code up to now:

```
 _graphClient
            .Cypher
            .Match("(user:UserAccount)-[:HasPermission]->(permission:Permission)")
            .With("user, collect(permission) as permissions")
            // I need to call the stored procedure here.
            .ReturnDistinct(
                (userAccount) =>
                                new
                                {
                                    UserAccount = userAccount.As<UserAccount>()
                                });
```

Comment: I don't use graphclient I send cypher querys to the database so much easier. also it is complicated with label UserAccount and return UserAccount

Comment: I'd consider the same myself but I really like the serialization you get with neo4jclient. Although if you have an example with that and call stored procedure in, i'd be happy to see it!

Comment: i just send it  then I fill a class with my result. If you want to do something special the c# libs are not working well.  I am c# programmer myself.

Comment: Ah ok, so you just fill the class manually? Would you consider providing a code example answer? If so i'll open a new question (although the answer you would give would kind of solve my problem, it probably wouldn't be a direct answer to the question and i'd like you to get the credit for your effort).

Comment: I can do that, but It will take some time. i don't care about credit.

Comment: Ok that would be great, i'd be really interesting in seeing how you've solved this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave the `IRawGraphClient` version below, but for version `1.1.0.39` (just published today) you can use `Call` and `Yield` directly:

```
_graphClient.Cypher
    .Match("(user:UserAccount)-[:HasPermission]->(permission:Permission)")
    .With("user, collect(permission) as permissions")
    .Call("apoc.map.setKey(user, 'permissions', permissions)").Yield("value AS UserAccount")
    .ReturnDistinct(
        (userAccount) => new { UserAccount = userAccount.As<UserAccount>() });
```

---

**OLD VERSION (Avoid if you can)**

Did you try the `IRawGraphClient` as I suggested in the GitHub bug you raised?

In essence you can cast the `GraphClient` instance you have to an `IRawGraphClient` instance:

```
IRawGraphClient rgc = (IRawGraphClient) client;
```

and then call with a query - it's a bit clunky, but would be like this:

```
var queryText = @"MATCH(user:UserAccount)-[:HasPermission]->(permission:Permission) 
WITH user, collect(permission) as permissions
CALL apoc.map.setKey( user, 'permissions', permissions ) YIELD value as UserAccount
RETURN UserAccount"

var cypherQuery = new CypherQuery(queryText, null, CypherResultMode.Projection);
var results = rgc.ExecuteGetCypherResults<UserAccount>(cypherQuery);
```

I *think* that will work - I don't have a 3.0 setup to test on at the moment, so can't be 100% sure, but please try and see.

I'll aim to get a `.Call`/`.Yield<T>` method sorted somepoint

Comment: Thanks for getting back to chris. I didn't know where the best place to raise the question (here or github). I'll give this a try. I was avoiding using IRawGraphClient as the docs state that you shouldn't use it unless you really need to and it can change at any point but if this is an acceptable use case then i'll give it a try.

Comment: Yer, it's a pain, but in this case it's the best approach, I'll work at getting 'Call' and Yield there ASAP so you can go back to a proper approach!

Comment: I did a post - that might help: http://geekswithblogs.net/cskardon/archive/2016/06/22/calling-stored-procs-in-neo4j-using-neo4jclient-ndashthe-hacky-way-again.aspx

Comment: Updated the client to have the `Call` etc methods

Comment: Thanks Chris! That's a very fast turn around! Much appreciated!