# How to return a list of composite objects in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I wanted to return a composite object, based on an exisiting node, I know that I could to this: (thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878115/how-to-return-a-composite-object-in-neo4j-cypher) post)

```
MATCH(...)-[:HAS_DB]->(db: Database {name: "my_database")

WITH { name: db.name,
       format: db.format,
     } AS database

RETURN database;
```

This would return an object based on but not exactly my `Database` node.

However, I would like to return composite objects for a collection of nodes, not just for one node:

I tried this, but it seems like `FOREACH` is only appropriate for `List<T>`.

```
MATCH(...)-[:HAS_DB]->(databases: Database)

FOREACH (db IN databases |
         RETURN {
            name: db.name,
            format: db.format
         }
        )
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MATCH(...)-[:HAS_DB]->(db: Database {name: "my_database")
WITH DISTINCT db
Return COLLECT( { name: db.name,
       format: db.format,
     }) AS database
```